# Google Apps Script: How to merge two arrays conditionally?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a 2D array having a title in its first element of its 1D array and "trailing" or not at the beginning of the title.  I like to add trailing data to the end of its same category parent data, "InterestExpense" or "IncomeTax".  How can I do that?

```
array = [['trailingInterestExpense', 4], ['InterestExpense', 1, 2, 3],
  ['trailingIncomeTax', 4], ['IncomeTax', 10, 20, 30]]
```

My expected result is:

```
array = [['InterestExpense', 1, 2, 3, 4],['IncomeTax', 10, 20, 30, 40]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your expected value of `array = [['InterestExpense', 1, 2, 3, 4],['IncomeTax', 10, 20, 30, 40]]`, I guessed your `['trailingIncomeTax', 4]` might be `['trailingIncomeTax', 40]`. If my understanding is correct, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
const keys = ["InterestExpense", "IncomeTax"]; // This is from your question.
const array = [['trailingInterestExpense', 4], ['InterestExpense', 1, 2, 3], ['trailingIncomeTax', 40], ['IncomeTax', 10, 20, 30]]; // This is from your question.

const obj = array.reduce((o, [a, ...b]) => {
  const key = keys.find(k => a.includes(k));
  if (key) o[key] = o[key] ? [...o[key], ...b] : b;
  return o;
}, {});
const res = keys.map(k => [k, ...obj[k].sort((a, b) => a - b)]);
console.log(res) // [["InterestExpense",1,2,3,4],["IncomeTax",10,20,30,40]]
```

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, it's awesome.  Your understanding is correct.  You are always a great teacher.   Thank you always!

Answer (score 0):

I made a small change to @Tanaike's, adding `array.sort((a, b) => (a[0].charCodeAt(0) - b[0].charCodeAt(0)))` right after "var array", because
in a real world situation trailing data are placed randomly in the array, and depending on its index location, the output from @Tanaike's code was different.

```
function test() {

  const keys = ["InterestExpense", "IncomeTax"]; // This is from your question.
  var array = [['trailingInterestExpense', 0.4], ['InterestExpense', 1, 2, 3], ['trailingIncomeTax', 0.4], ['IncomeTax', 10, 20, 30]]; // This is from your question.
  // Added this line to rearrange trailing data to the end of the array
  array.sort((a, b) => (a[0].charCodeAt(0) - b[0].charCodeAt(0)));
  console.log(array)

  const obj = array.reduce((o, [a, ...b]) => {
    const key = keys.find(k => a.includes(k));
    if (key) o[key] = o[key] ? [...o[key], ...b] : b;
    return o;
  }, {});
  const res = keys.map(k => [k, ...obj[k]]);
  console.log(res) // [["InterestExpense",1,2,3,0.4],["IncomeTax",10,20,30,0.4]]

}
```